# How to import .txt file generted by Mathematica in list form using Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I have a .txt file which contains numeric values as {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}} ("Mathematica Form"). I need to import it on array using python [[1 2 3]

4 5 6].

my file.txt contains 500 rows by 3000 columns written as {{1,2,3,..},{0,1,1,1, ..},{},....{1,2,3,..., }}.

I have used this code

```
import numpy;
from numpy import *;
data = loadtxt("file.txt");
```

Comment: Give a concrete example for a text file. Are there multiple strings such as '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}' in there or just one? If there are multiple, what's the expected output? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to read in a text file, or do we have to start there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate a string containing a Python literal:

```
import ast

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n', '')

data = data.replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']')
mylist = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(mylist)
```